# Creating curves in Python

Tags: python, scripting, bezier-curves

I am new to Blender scripting and I am getting some unexpected behavior when trying to add a curve through a Python script. I am using this code:

```
import bpy
import math
import pdb
from mathutils import Vector

# print all objects
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    print(obj.name)
    if("Curve" in obj.name):
        print("found")
        bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].objects.unlink(obj)
        bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)

for cur in bpy.data.curves:
    print(cur.name)
    bpy.data.curves.remove(cur)

# sample data
coords = [(1,0,1), (2,0,0), (3,0,1)]

# create the Curve Datablock
curveData = bpy.data.curves.new('myCurve', type='CURVE')
curveData.dimensions = '3D'
curveData.resolution_u = 2

# map coords to spline
polyline = curveData.splines.new('POLY')
polyline.points.add(len(coords))
for i, coord in enumerate(coords):
    x,y,z = coord
    polyline.points[i].co = (x, y, z, 1)

# create Object
curveOB = bpy.data.objects.new('myCurve', curveData)
curveData.bevel_depth = 0.01

# attach to scene and validate context
scn = bpy.context.scene
scn.objects.link(curveOB)
scn.objects.active = curveOB
```

And this is the result I get.

[image]

I am confused why there are four coordinates. Blender seems to create one additional point at the coordinate origin (0,0,0), connecting it with the last point from my data. Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Comment: To run the script above in Blender 2.8, I think the last two lines need to be changed to `scn.collection.objects.link(curveOB)` (see [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145658/link-new-object-to-scene-with-python-in-2-8)) and `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = curveOB` (see [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126577/blender-2-8-api-python-set-active-object))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution was simple enough. I changed

```
polyline.points.add(len(coords))
```

to

```
polyline.points.add(len(coords)-1)
```

as found here:

http://blenderscripting.blogspot.de/2011/05/blender-25-python-bezier-from-list-of.html

Comment: Can you elaborate, eg `splines.new(...)` returns a spline with one point.

Comment: That's strange, because output of `for i in range(len(polyline.points)):
    print(polyline.points[i].co.xy)` does not contain (0,0)

Comment: However this code `polyline = curveData.splines.new('POLY')
    for i in range(len(polyline.points)): 
        print(polyline.points[i].co.xy)` prints only one point (0,0) ! So by creation, there is always one point in the array, and you even can access it `polyline.points[0].co = (1, 1, 1, 1)` but nothing changes. That's strange behavior, seem a bug