# Add > Path with custom geometry using Python

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I am writing a Python script and in part of it I want to do an **Add** > **Curve** > **Path** operation, but instead of the default 5-vert straight path, I want one at the object origin (which I have pre-defined with coordinates `orig_x` `orig_y` `orig_z`), and then another at some other location (let's say coords `end_x` `end_y` `end_z`).

**Instead of the default primitive NURBS path, I want the script to add my own, which is just 2 vertices.**

Here's that line of my script as it is currently:

`bpy.ops.curve.primitive_nurbs_path_add(radius=1, enter_editmode=False, align='CURSOR', location=(orig_x, orig_y, orig_z), scale=(1, 1, 1))`

I can't figure out if I should start by deleting all the vertices, then re-adding two, OR if I should try to select just the second [1] and fourth [3] indices and Dissolve Vertices... I've tried both approaches without success. I'm doing something wrong when trying to target those verts.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/61266/86891

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks for the clue. It helps a little, but also raises new questions about how that person removed the existing verts. I'm still studying it.

Comment: Well the idea is not to use the operator but rather instantiate an empty curve and add the relevant points rather than working backwards from a primitive curve added with an operator. I personnaly have trouble with both so I won't be of much more help but still, food for thought

Comment: Thanks, batFINGER! By following links from your link, I found [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/120074/2952) that when I put the answers together, appears to be the sort of example I needed.

Comment: Good one.  Expanded https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180148/create-curve-from-numpy-array-using-python to have a 2 point nurbs option.   Can prob close this down as a dupe then?

Comment: @batFINGER Yes, I think so. I appreciate the nudge in the right direction.

Comment: NP Often see don't use operators in comments, my rule of thumb in particular is avoid edit mode toggling and edit mode operators..